# Not getting response from upwork API

Tags: upwork-api

I am trying to get all companies using below api

```
var companies = new Companies(api);
  companies.getList(function (error, data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(error);
  });
```

My app have all the permission still I am getting below error,

```
{"server_time":1586893220,"error":{"status":403,"code":403,"message":"This APP has no access to requested resource"}}
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for [List companies API](https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#companies-and-teams_list-companies), the API key must have the following permissions: "View the structure of your companies/teams", see section "Required key permissions".

Please, revisit your key and adjust the permissions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response.